# How to decode binary data embedded in XML using XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt, lotus-notes, saxon

I have XML data extracted from a legacy Lotus Notes application. The XML has embedded binary data. I am guessing, based on information on the IBM Lotus Notes website, that it is encoded in base64 format, but I am not certain of this. Some of the binary data appears to be images, while some of it appears to be embedded MS Word documents. I am using the Saxon XSLT processor. How can I decode this binary data using XSLT?

The data looks roughly like this:

```
<objectref version='2' name='EXT12682' class='Word.Document.8'
    displayformat='metafile' description='Microsoft Word Document' classid='{00020906-0000-0000-c000-000000000046}'
    storageformat='structstorage'><picture height='289px' width='625px' scaledheight='3.0104in'
        scaledwidth='6.5104in'><notesbitmap>illegiblegobbledygookillegiblegobbledygookillegiblegobbledygookillegiblegobbledygookillegiblegobbledygookillegiblegobbledygookillegiblegobbledygookillegiblegobbledygookillegiblegobbledygookillegiblegobbledygook</notesbitmap></picture></objectref>


<file hosttype='bytearraypage'
    compression='none' flags='storedindoc' name='STG12172'>
    <created><datetime dst='true'>20080924T171730,05-04</datetime></created>
    <modified><datetime dst='true'>20080924T171730,05-04</datetime></modified><filedata>illegiblegobbledygookillegiblegobbledygookillegiblegobbledygookillegiblegobbledygookillegiblegobbledygookillegiblegobbledygookillegiblegobbledygookillegiblegobbledygookillegiblegobbledygookillegiblegobbledygook</filedata></file>
```

Comment: The commercial editions of Saxon have some support for dealing with base64 encoded data, see the functions `base64Binary-to-string/octets` documented on http://saxonica.com/html/documentation/functions/saxon/. There is also the http://saxonica.com/html/documentation/functions/expath%2Dbinary/ module.

Comment: Thanks for the info... It looks like I still need an additional step to view the result as an image or Word doc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recent releases of Saxon (PE and EE) include an implementation of the EXPath binary module (http://expath.org/spec/binary) which contains everything you need to manipulate binary data - except of course a specification of the binary data that you want to manipulate. If you know what the input structure is, and if you know what the output you want to produce should look like, then the binary functions should help you, but I fear from your question that you don't really know either.

If you believe that the binary data is, for example, a base64-encoded JPEG file, then you don't actually need the EXPath binary module - the EXPath file module (also implemented in Saxon PE and EE) should be enough. See http://expath.org/spec/file#fn.write-binary

You can do:

```
file:write-binary("output.jpeg", xs:base64Binary(jpegBitMap))
```

to write the contents of a binary element as an external file, and then you can try to open the file using an application that understands the relevant format.

(Be careful with these methods because they have side-effects, which doesn't fit very well into XQuery or XSLT. For example, don't try calling them within a variable initializer which won't get called if the variable is never used.)

Comment: Thanks! Although I'm still a bit confused about the fact that each XML file can have multiple embedded binary objects. Does that mean that each embedded object should be written to a separate file?

Comment: We don't know what you want to do with the data, so how can we tell?